How to find which query is attached to cursor
I see running queries like  FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed portal 847>"
How can I find which query is attached to this cursor?

You should query pg_cursors:
SELECT statement FROM pg_cursors
WHERE name = '<unnamed portal 847>';


Thank you very much Mr Albe.

Sorry to bother you again but pg_cursors data is only available to its session. I want to see another sessions cursor.

There is no way to do that, because that information is only stored in the backend processes memory, which is not visible outside the process.
